# Authentication not working in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on a Facebook canvas application. I created a sample project using the latest ASP.net MVC3 RC2, and use the exactly same settings as provided in the sample (MVC2). But it's not working. After a user clicks `Allow` to grant the permission, there are an unending redirects between the site and Facebook. Does anybody have experience on this problem? Any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Are you using the release download or did you compile the source code yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is solved by the Facebook C# SDK...

Comment: How? What does one have to **do** with the SDK to make authentication work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in web forms application. But the error resolved after setting Site URL under Website tab (in facebook app registration settings) to Canvas URL (under facebook integration settings).